# Why is my arr.length not consistently printing out values and instead always printing out "0"?

Tags: java, arrays

From my research, my first error was populating the array in the switch case. I fixed it so it is populated outside. I did a few tests and arr.length will give me the output of 1000 as expected, but it should be 500 (if I put 500 as the upperbound, how would I make values between 1-1000?). Case 5 works for some reason which uses arr.length as well.

I want to have 500 integers between the value of 1-1000 print out various outcomes. There are no errors in the code. All cases except case 2 & 7 work.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class ArrayMenu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Pick an option 1-7, 0 to exit");
        byte menu;
        Random num = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
            arr[i] = num.nextInt(500);
        }

        do {
            menu = scan.nextByte();
            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
                        System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    }
                    break;


                case 2:
                    int mean = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
                        int sum = 0;
                        int z = arr[i];
                        sum = sum + z;
                        mean = sum / arr.length;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
                    break;


                case 3:
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
                        int y = arr[i];
                        if (y % 2 != 0) System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
                        int x = arr[i];
                        if (x % 2 == 0) System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    }
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Median is " + arr[arr.length / 2]);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("First is " + arr[0]);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Last is " + arr[arr.length - 1]);
                    System.out.println(arr.length);
                    break;
            }

        } while (menu != 0);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Bonus question: how would I randomly fill with negative values instead of only positive?

Comment: On the one hand you're saying `arr.length` is "always printing out 0", then you're saying  `arr.length' "outputs 1000 as expected".. Which is it?  What's your question?

Comment: To convert a postive number to negative, multiply by `-1.0`

Comment: I confused myself, I edited the question

Comment: @ScaryWombat would that not make all the values negative? Say I wanted the array to randomly fill with values between -500 to 500.

Comment: You are only filling up the first 500 elements, so of course the last value will be `0`, have another loop that does the negative number.

Comment: Gotcha, so how do I fix it? I realize this but I'm not sure how to go about fixing the issue as mentioned in my edited question

Comment: In what sense does 2 not work? Do you mean that it takes into account that 500 of the numbers you are finding the mean of are zero?

Comment: Sorry, but saying that there are no errors in the code when at least three items don't work is hubris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that case 5 also doesn't work. The mean is not defined as 'the middle in a random assortment', there is nothing special about the 500th element. It's defined as: "Once you've sorted it all, the middle element". You aren't sorting anything.

Without resorting to calling `Arrays.sort` (I don't know if your homework assignment allows you to do this), case 5 is in fact the one that's the most complicated to write.

Furthermore, you have an array of 1000 slots (so, `array.length` is 1000), and you wrote a bunch of code that assumes 1000 is in fact how large your array actually is - such as your 'print the last' code returning the `[999]` element. However, at the start, you only fill the first 500 with random numbers, the remaining 500 remain unfilled, which means they retain their initial value, which is `0`.

Thus, we get to:

> All cases except case 2 & 7 work.

No, they don't.

Programming is really, really hard. Before concluding that your stuff works just because it compiled and it ran, check that the outputs you see actually make sense.

> ````
> for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
>    arr[i] = num.nextInt(500);
> }```
> ````

The first use of '500' is how many times you want to loop. If you want to fill the whole array, use 1000 there. The second use of 500 decides from amongst how many numbers you want to pick random numbers. 500 means that you get any number, from as low as 0 to as large as 499 (which is a total span of 500 numbers).

You've used `<=` and that's the mistake; use `<`. An array of size 1000 has valid indices `[0]` all the way up to and including `[999]`, but not `[1000]`. Think about it: if 0 is the first element, then 999 is the 1000th element, and `[1000]` would be the 1001st element, which isn't there. Thus:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   arr[i] = num.nextInt(500);
   // or if you want uniform from -500 to 500 all inclusive:
   arr[i] = num.nextInt(1001) - 500;
}
```

why 1001? Because that's how many different numbers you can generate: 500 negative numbers, 500 positive numbers.. and 0. 1001. (That goes some way into showing you why java is 0-based, the math tends to be less weird that way).

Comment: Thanks for the succinct reply, that really explains a lot as a 1st semester Java student. If you don't mind, could you explain in layman terms what the method nextInt() is doing in obj num.nextInt()? I am not familiar with libraries so a basic explanation would also be much appreciated.

Comment: The mean isn't the middle element; that's the median.

Comment: nextInt will fetch the next token from whatever your scanner is reading (in your code, presumably, System.in, which is generally your keyboard). It will then attempt to parse that token as an integer and return it. If it isn't, that will throw an exception. tokens are things in between spaces (unless you told the scanner that the delimiter is something else, such as a newline).

Answer (score 1):

This is your code right now:

```java
case 2:
    int mean = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        int z = arr[i];
        sum = sum + z;
        mean = sum / arr.length;
    }
    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
    break;
```

However, there are a couple of mistakes here. First of all, the `mean` could be a decimal, so you should declare it as a `double`, not an `int`. Also, there's no need to assign it in the loop; you can just assign it once after the loop. You're also redeclaring `sum` every loop, which means the sum never gets incremented. Here's the fixed code:

```java
case 2:
    double mean;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    mean = (double) sum / arr.length;
    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
    break;
```

Also, for this line:

```java
int[] arr = new int[1000];
```

You allocate an array of 1000 elements, but only fill from 0 to 500 inclusive (which is 501 elements). If you want `arr.length` to work properly, only allocate what you need:

```java
int[] arr = new int[501];
```

If you don't want to manually allocate, then use [ArrayLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead.

If you want a negative number between -500 and 500, then generate one between 0 and 1000 then subtract 500:

```java
rand.nextInt(1000) - 500
```